# Roman numerals look and say sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, roman-numerals

I was practicing [question 1](https://www.olympiad.org.uk/papers/2020/bio/bio20-exam.pdf#page=2) of the 2020 british informatics olympiad past paper:

> The Roman look-and-say description of a string (of Is, Vs, Xs, Ls, Cs, Ds and Ms) is made by taking each
> block of adjacent identical letters and replacing it with the number of occurrences of that letter, given in
> Roman numerals (*), followed by the letter itself. A block of adjacent identical letters is never broken
> into smaller pieces before describing it.

> Write a program that reads in a Roman numeral representing a number between 1
> and 3999 inclusive, followed by n (1 ≤ n ≤ 50).
> You should apply the Roman look-and-say description n times and then output the
> number of Is in the final description, followed by the number of Vs.

I wrote this python code to attempt to solve this:

```py
ROMAN_NUMERALS = {
    1000: "M",
    900: "CM",
    500: "D",
    400: "DC",
    100: "C",
    90: "XC",
    50: "L",
    40: "XL",
    10: "X",
    9: "IX",
    5: "V",
    4: "IV",
    1: "I"
}


def convert_to_roman_numeral(n):
    s = ""
    while n > 0:
        for key, value in ROMAN_NUMERALS.items():
            if n - key >= 0:
                s += value
                n -= key

                break

    return s


def get_look_and_say_string(initial_string):
    output = ""

    while initial_string != "":
        for i in range(len(initial_string)):
            if initial_string[i] != initial_string[0]:
                output += convert_to_roman_numeral(i) + initial_string[i - 1]

                initial_string = initial_string[i:]

                break

            elif len(initial_string) == i + 1:
                output += convert_to_roman_numeral(i + 1) + initial_string[i]

                return output


s, apply_times = input().split()

for i in range(int(apply_times)):
    s = get_look_and_say_string(s)

print(s.count("I"), s.count("V"))
```

For example, given the input `MMXX 1`, it outputs `4 0`.

(A list of test cases can be found in the mark scheme [here](https://www.olympiad.org.uk/papers/2020/bio/bio20-marks.pdf#page=2))

I would be grateful to hear about any improvements that could be made to this code.

Comment: The code requires that the order of dict entries in `ROMAN_NUMERALS` is preserved. This is true for CPython since 3.6 and is part of the standard since Python 3.7. This should be specified explicitly or, as you don't use `ROMAN_NUMERALS` as dict but only as sequence, you could instead use a list or tuple of tuples `(key, value)` to avoid any possible problems.

Answer (score 5):

Michael Butscher is correct to suggest that you should not be using a dictionary; just use a tuple of tuples. Otherwise, for a light refactor:

Add type hints to your function signatures.

Replace your incremental string concatenation with `''.join(generator)` style, which performs better under some scenarios (though you will want to measure this, and I haven't).

Replace `for i in range(len(initial_string)):` with a call to `enumerate` so that you get both the current symbol and its index.

Your `elif len(initial_string) == i + 1:` is a smell, because it's written to execute at the end of a loop - so just... move it out of the loop, under an `else`.

Separate an outer `input(); print()` function from a testable, non-console function; and write unit tests.

```py
"""
https://www.olympiad.org.uk/papers/2020/bio/bio20-marks.pdf#page=2
"""

from typing import Iterator

ROMAN_NUMERALS = (
    (1000, 'M'),
    (900, 'CM'),
    (500, 'D'),
    (400, 'DC'),
    (100, 'C'),
    (90, 'XC'),
    (50, 'L'),
    (40, 'XL'),
    (10, 'X'),
    (9, 'IX'),
    (5, 'V'),
    (4, 'IV'),
    (1, 'I'),
)


def convert_to_roman_numeral(n: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    while n > 0:
        for increment, symbol in ROMAN_NUMERALS:
            new_n = n - increment
            if new_n >= 0:
                yield symbol
                n = new_n
                break


def get_look_and_say_string(initial_string: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    while initial_string != '':
        for i, str_i in enumerate(initial_string):
            if str_i != initial_string[0]:
                yield from convert_to_roman_numeral(i)
                yield initial_string[i - 1]
                initial_string = initial_string[i:]
                break
        else:
            yield from convert_to_roman_numeral(len(initial_string))
            yield initial_string[-1]
            return


def problem(input_str: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
    s, apply_times = input_str.split()
    for _ in range(int(apply_times)):
        s = ''.join(get_look_and_say_string(s))
    return s.count('I'), s.count('V')


def test_op() -> None:
    assert problem('MMXX 1') == (4, 0)


def test_official() -> None:
    assert problem('MMXX 3') == (6, 2)
    assert problem('C 1') == (1, 0)
    assert problem('V 1') == (1, 1)
    assert problem('III 2') == (2, 1)
    assert problem('I 7') == (6, 2)
    assert problem('MMXX 8') == (30, 12)
    assert problem('II 20') == (101, 37)
    assert problem('IV 20') == (121, 46)
    assert problem('MDCLX 30') == (1795, 695)
    assert problem('M 50') == (2858, 1103)
    assert problem('V 50') == (2858, 1104)
    assert problem('MMDCCCLXXXVIII 50') == (19013, 7333)


def main() -> None:
    i, v = problem(input())
    print(i, v)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_op()
    test_official()
    # main()
```

### Logarithmic lookup

Your inner `convert_to_roman_numeral` should probably be changed so that it does a bisection search to get digits:

```py
import bisect
from typing import Iterator

ROMAN_VALUES = (
    1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000,
)

ROMAN_SYMBOLS = (
    'I', 'IV', 'V', 'IX', 'X', 'XL', 'L', 'XC', 'C', 'DC', 'D', 'CM', 'M',
)


def convert_to_roman_numeral(n: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    hi = len(ROMAN_VALUES)
    while n > 0:
        i_low = bisect.bisect_right(a=ROMAN_VALUES, x=n, hi=hi) - 1
        value = ROMAN_VALUES[i_low]
        repeat = n // value
        yield ROMAN_SYMBOLS[i_low] * repeat
        n -= value * repeat
        hi = i_low
```

### Direct logarithmic bound

You can fairly straightforwardly prove that for some *n* input to `convert_to_roman_numeral`, the index *i* into the `ROMAN` arrays is bounded by

$$
\lceil 4 \log_{10} \frac n 4 \rceil
\le i \le
\lfloor 4 \log_{10} n \rfloor
$$

To demonstrate, here are values from 10 through 100 and their index bounds:

[image: index bounds]

From this, you can write an alternative `convert_to_roman_numeral` that starts on a bound and loops linearly through a very short (1-2) sequence of values to find the target. Whereas in theory this is O(1) compared to bisection's O(log(n)), it still performs slightly better than this; to compare:

```py
import bisect
import math
import timeit
from typing import Iterator

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


ROMAN_NUMERALS_DICT = {
    1000: "M",
    900: "CM",
    500: "D",
    400: "DC",
    100: "C",
    90: "XC",
    50: "L",
    40: "XL",
    10: "X",
    9: "IX",
    5: "V",
    4: "IV",
    1: "I"
}
def convert_roman_op(n):
    s = ""
    while n > 0:
        for key, value in ROMAN_NUMERALS_DICT.items():
            if n - key >= 0:
                s += value
                n -= key

                break
    return s


ROMAN_NUMERALS_TUPLE = (
    (1000, 'M'),
    (900, 'CM'),
    (500, 'D'),
    (400, 'DC'),
    (100, 'C'),
    (90, 'XC'),
    (50, 'L'),
    (40, 'XL'),
    (10, 'X'),
    (9, 'IX'),
    (5, 'V'),
    (4, 'IV'),
    (1, 'I'),
)
def convert_roman_inner(n: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    while n > 0:
        for increment, symbol in ROMAN_NUMERALS_TUPLE:
            new_n = n - increment
            if new_n >= 0:
                yield symbol
                n = new_n
                break
def convert_roman_gen(n: int) -> str:
    return ''.join(convert_roman_inner(n))


ROMAN_VALUES = (
    1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000,
)

ROMAN_SYMBOLS = (
    'I', 'IV', 'V', 'IX', 'X', 'XL', 'L', 'XC', 'C', 'DC', 'D', 'CM', 'M',
)
def convert_roman_inner_bisect(n: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    hi = len(ROMAN_VALUES)
    while n > 0:
        i_low = bisect.bisect_right(a=ROMAN_VALUES, x=n, hi=hi) - 1
        value = ROMAN_VALUES[i_low]
        repeat = n // value
        yield ROMAN_SYMBOLS[i_low] * repeat
        n -= value * repeat
        hi = i_low
def convert_roman_bisect(n: int) -> str:
    return ''.join(convert_roman_inner_bisect(n))


def convert_roman_inner_log(n: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    max_index = len(ROMAN_VALUES) - 1
    while n > 0:
        top = min(max_index, int(4*math.log10(n)))
        value = ROMAN_VALUES[top]
        while value > n:
            top -= 1
            value = ROMAN_VALUES[top]
        repeat = n // value
        yield ROMAN_SYMBOLS[top] * repeat
        n -= value * repeat
def convert_roman_log(n: int) -> str:
    return ''.join(convert_roman_inner_log(n))


methods = (
    convert_roman_op,
    convert_roman_gen,
    convert_roman_bisect,
    convert_roman_log,
)


def benchmark() -> None:
    results = []

    for size in (
        10**np.linspace(0, 5, 101)
    ).astype(int):
        reps = max(1, 100 // size)
        ref = None

        for method in methods:
            def run() -> None:
                nonlocal ref
                output = method(size)
                if ref is None:
                    ref = output
                else:
                    assert ref == output
            for _ in range(reps):
                t = timeit.timeit(stmt=run, number=1)
                results.append((size, method.__name__, t))
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        data=results,
        columns=['size', 'method', 'dur'],
    )

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax: plt.Axes
    seaborn.lineplot(ax=ax, data=df, x='size', y='dur', hue='method')
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    benchmark()
```

[image: benchmark roman]

### Iterating in look-and-say

AJNeufeld has an excellent suggestion to use `itertools` (or `more_itertools` which I don't demonstrate). It both cleans up and speeds up your main loop.

```py
"""
https://www.olympiad.org.uk/papers/2020/bio/bio20-marks.pdf#page=2
"""

import bisect
import itertools
import time
from typing import Iterator

ROMAN_VALUES = (
    1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000,
)

ROMAN_SYMBOLS = (
    'I', 'IV', 'V', 'IX', 'X', 'XL', 'L', 'XC', 'C', 'DC', 'D', 'CM', 'M',
)


def convert_to_roman_numeral(n: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    hi = len(ROMAN_VALUES)
    while n > 0:
        i_low = bisect.bisect_right(a=ROMAN_VALUES, x=n, hi=hi) - 1
        value = ROMAN_VALUES[i_low]
        repeat = n // value
        yield ROMAN_SYMBOLS[i_low] * repeat
        n -= value * repeat
        hi = i_low


def get_look_and_say_op(initial_string):
    output = ""

    while initial_string != "":
        for i in range(len(initial_string)):
            if initial_string[i] != initial_string[0]:
                output += ''.join(convert_to_roman_numeral(i)) + initial_string[i - 1]

                initial_string = initial_string[i:]

                break

            elif len(initial_string) == i + 1:
                output += ''.join(convert_to_roman_numeral(i + 1)) + initial_string[i]

                return output


def problem_op(input_str):
    s, apply_times = input_str.split()
    for _ in range(int(apply_times)):
        s = get_look_and_say_op(s)
    return s.count('I'), s.count('V')


def get_look_and_say_gen(initial_string: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    while initial_string != '':
        for i, str_i in enumerate(initial_string):
            if str_i != initial_string[0]:
                yield from convert_to_roman_numeral(i)
                yield initial_string[i - 1]
                initial_string = initial_string[i:]
                break
        else:
            yield from convert_to_roman_numeral(len(initial_string))
            yield initial_string[-1]
            return


def problem_gen(input_str: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
    s, apply_times = input_str.split()
    for _ in range(int(apply_times)):
        s = ''.join(get_look_and_say_gen(s))
    return s.count('I'), s.count('V')


def get_look_and_say_ajneufeld(initial_string: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    for letter, repeats in (
        (k, sum(1 for _ in g))
        for k, g in itertools.groupby(initial_string)
    ):
        yield from convert_to_roman_numeral(repeats)
        yield letter


def problem_ajneufeld(input_str: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
    s, apply_times = input_str.split()
    for _ in range(int(apply_times)):
        s = ''.join(get_look_and_say_ajneufeld(s))
    return s.count('I'), s.count('V')


def benchmark() -> None:
    largest_test_case = 'MMDCCCLXXXVIII 50'
    for method in (
        problem_op,
        problem_gen,
        problem_ajneufeld,
    ):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        result = method(largest_test_case)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        assert result == (19013, 7333)
        print(method.__name__, end - start)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    benchmark()
```

```
problem_op 0.12485683699924266
problem_gen 0.09267444600118324
problem_ajneufeld 0.0854689560001134
```

Comment: I cringe when I see your `get_look_and_say_string(initial_string)` implementation.  Use: `for letter, repeats in more_itertools.run_length.encode(initial_string):` `yield from convert_to_roman_numeral(repeats)` `yield letter`.  Otherwise, superb answer.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I appreciate that. I can only assume, however, that the Olympiad doesn't support third-party libraries.

Comment: True, but the OP was only doing it “for practice”, so I thought it would be allowed.  Since it is part of the standard library, `itertools` should be allowed: `for letter, repeats in ((k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(iterable)):` …

Comment: @AJNeufeld I like it! I've included it in a comparison.

Comment: I feel like `get_look_and_say_string` would be greatly simplified by `re.search(r'((.)\2*)',initial_string)`.